# Magento2.3: Undefined variable: customergroupid

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account, create-account

I'm getting the below error when I browse the following URL:

http://127.0.0.1/mywebsite/customer/account/create

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: customergroupid in /var/www/html/mywebsite/app/design/frontend/Module/vendor/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/templates/form/userattributes.phtml on line 27

I have checked the path and see I have below code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Create account form template
 *
 * @see \Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Block\Form
 */
/* @var $block \Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Block\Form */
?>
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customergroupid = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
    //echo $customergroupid;

}
?>
<?php if(($customergroupid == 4) || ($customergroupid == 5) || ($customergroupid == 6)): ?>
<?php if ($block->hasUserDefinedAttributes()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->isShowContainer()): ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php foreach ($block->getUserDefinedAttributes() as $attribute):?>
        <?php $attributeContent = $block->getAttributeHtml($attribute);?>
        <?php if ($attributeContent): ?>
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $attributeContent ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php if ($block->isShowContainer()): ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define **$customergroupid** this variable before if condition with `NULL` value, or update your file with below content

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Create account form template
 *
 * @see \Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Block\Form
 */
/* @var $block \Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Block\Form */
?>
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customergroupid = '';
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customergroupid = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
    //echo $customergroupid;

}
?>
<?php if(($customergroupid == 4) || ($customergroupid == 5) || ($customergroupid == 6)): ?>
<?php if ($block->hasUserDefinedAttributes()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->isShowContainer()): ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php foreach ($block->getUserDefinedAttributes() as $attribute):?>
        <?php $attributeContent = $block->getAttributeHtml($attribute);?>
        <?php if ($attributeContent): ?>
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $attributeContent ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php if ($block->isShowContainer()): ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this will fix your issue!

Comment: Thanks. Its working now.

Comment: Approve my answer if it helps. Thanks :)